# Import server imports automatically in meteor shell

Tags: meteor

How can I instruct `meteor shell` to automatically import `'/imports/startup/server/index.js';`

I want to have everything that's available on server, immediately available in the shell (collections, underscorejs, etc.)

I tried creating `'/imports/startup/shell/index.js';`, but that does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Files in /imports are not loaded by default, but files in /server are. Put your import code in, for example `server/shell.js`